# C# HttpContext. Не изменяется Item

Tags: c#, сессия

Храню настройки пользователя в HttpContext.Item["user_settings"]. У пользователя открыто два окна с одинаковым SessionId. В одном он меняет настройки, однако в другом, при вызове контроллера, обновляющего страницу, значение в user_settings не меняются.

Что не так?

Comment: Под тегами к вопросу есть надпись `править`. Для иллюстрации проблемы вам нужно добавить код контроллера, который вызывает эту проблему.

Answer (score 3):

`HttpContext` хранит данные только в рамках обработки одного HTTP-запроса.

Для хранения настроек пользователя следует использовать либо сессию (Session, HttpSessionState) - в таком случае настройки будут сбрасываться при закрытии браузера или по истечении времени, либо профиль (Profile, ProfileInfo) - в таком случае настройки будут сохраняться для пользователя всегда. Также можно хранить их в БД самостоятельно.

Comment: Понятно. Ну, в БД хранить - это очевидно. Оно там и хранится. Просто в чтобы процессе сессии не хочется лезть постоянно в базу. Один раз прочитал на старте - и достаточно.

Answer (score 2):

`HttpContext` (с тем, что Вы положили в его `Items`) существует в течение обработки одного запроса. На другой запрос создается другой контекст с новым (изначально пустым) набором `Items`. Используйте `Session`.